# Building a string based on columns from a GROUP

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join, aggregates

I have a table like this:

```
user 1    A
user 1    B
user 2    H
user 2    G
user 2    A
```

and I need a result like:

```
user 1   AB
user 2  HGA
```

Is there a way to obtain a result like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here we create some test data

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES (1,'A'),(1,'B'),(2,'H'),(2,'G'),(2,'A')
) AS f(id,col);
```

This should work,

```
SELECT id, array_to_string(array_agg(col), '')
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

Here is what we're doing,

1. GROUP BY id.
2. Build a PostgreSQL `text[]` (text array) of that column with `array_agg`
3. Convert the array back to text by joining on an empty string '' with `array_to_string`.

You can also use `string_agg`,

```
SELECT id, string_agg(col, '')
FROM foo
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I didn't know about the array_agg and array_to_string functions, but it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The better soluction is using `str_sum` agregate function

```
select 
user,
str_sum(column_name,'')
from table_name
group by user;
```

Comment: Error message: 'function str_sum(character varying, unknown) does not exist', but the below function worked!

Comment: your version postgres ?

Comment: I think you mean string_agg, I updated my example to show it.